# Undo echo command

Tags: command-line

I added a line to my gitignore file using echo but doing so made it override all the existing lines of code in the file.

```
echo /node_modules > .gitignore
```

Is there a way that I can undo the echo command besides doing a git reset to go back a commit?

Comment: Other than restore your backup, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, echo writes over the file. So a restore is in order. Depending on the operating system there might be a function for that but git should be the best solution IMHO.

Comment: `echo` itself won't overwrite any files, but the use of `>` will make the shell do so.

Comment: Yes and >> will append. But what I meant was that the operation described would overwrite the file.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that as I was writing it but it was too late. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the .gitignore was already checked in, you can pull the old version back simply with

```
git checkout .gitignore
```

What you really wanted to use was use `>>` to append rather than `>` to overwrite.